# Laravel/Lumen: View::share() alternative?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've been using Laravel for a long time, and I'm now writing a micro-project using Lumen.

I need to pass some variables to all views. In Laravel I can use the `View::share()` function in a middleware or in the controller's constructor, but in Lumen there is no `View` class, and it looks like all view functionality is simply `View::make()` alias.

Is there a way to share variables to all views?

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons, Lumen doesn't register facades and service providers the way Laravel does. While the Laravel facades are included with Lumen, only some are aliased (`View` not being one of them), and only if you uncomment the `$app->withFacedes();` line in `bootstrap/app.php` (you can check the [`Laravel\Lumen\Application::withFacades`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L766-L791) method to see which ones). So in order to use other facades such as `View`, you either need to alias the facade class yourself:

```
// "bootstrap/app.php" is a good place to add this
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\View', 'View');
```

Or you can include it with `use` wherever needed:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to share data with views in Lumen is:

```
app('view')->share(...);
```

Some of Laravel's functionality that is not explicitly described in Lumen documentation can be accessed with Lumen's `app()` helper function.